# django form radio input layout

Tags: python, django, django-forms

What is the "djangoy" way to approach this problem:

In my form class, I have a forms.ChoiceField whose widget is a forms.RadioSelect widget, one of whose choices needs to be presented with an inline text input (which is also a field in the form).  I'm using custom validation to ignore the text field when its radio choice is not selected.  When rendered, I want it to appear like below:

```
<ul>
<li><label for="id_rad_0"><input type="radio" id="id_rad_0" value="none" name="rad" /> No Textbox</label></li>
<li><label for="id_rad_1"><input type="radio" id="id_rad_1" value="one" name="rad" /> One Textbox: <input type="text" name="bar" id="id_bar" /></label></li>
</ul>
```

However, I can't simply produce this in my template, because the radio choices are not exposed.  I can't see a way to do this without tightly coupling my form to my template, or alternately, putting all of the presentation logic in the form class.  What is the *right* way to solve this problem?

**edit**

I realize that the above might just be an obscure problem, but I'm not sure exactly what other information I can provide in order to inspire someone to help me with this. I'm a much better backend programmer than web designer, and I'm on this project alone, so maybe it's a lack of education - is what I described simply poor design?  Should I just be designing this a different way? I'm really open to any suggestion here that will help me move past this.

**edit 2**

Per request, the current code, shortened to save sanity, names changed to protect the innocent:

```
# forms.py
from myapp.models import RatherComplicatedModel
from django import forms

class RatherComplicatedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #various and sundry code...
    RADIO_CHOICES = (
        ('none', "No Textbox"),
        ('one', "One Textbox: "),
    )
    # although I've abbreviated the model, 'rad' does not appear in the model;
    # it merely provides input to the un-provided clean function
    rad = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),choices=RADIO_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = RatherComplicatedModel
```

-

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class RatherComplicatedModel(models.Model):
    #some other stuff...
    bar = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
```

Comment: Can you please show us the code of your form class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anton's answer worked, and was a decent answer for a while there - but unfortunately it became unmaintainable.  So, taking a cue from [a diff](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/9230/forms.py.diff) attached to [django ticket #9230](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9230), I just monkey patched `django.forms.forms.BoundField`

```
from django import forms

def MonkeyPatchDjangoFormsBoundField():
    def prepare_widget_render(self, widget=None, attrs=None, only_initial=False):
        """
        Prepare the data needed for the widget rendering.
        """
        if not widget:
            widget = self.field.widget

        attrs = attrs or {}
        auto_id = self.auto_id
        if auto_id and 'id' not in attrs and 'id' not in widget.attrs:
            if not only_initial:
                attrs['id'] = auto_id
            else:
                attrs['id'] = self.html_initial_id

        if not only_initial:
            name = self.html_name
        else:
            name = self.html_initial_name

        return widget, name, attrs

    def as_widget(self, widget=None, attrs=None, only_initial=False):
        """
        Renders the field by rendering the passed widget, adding any HTML
        attributes passed as attrs.  If no widget is specified, then the
        field's default widget will be used.
        """
        widget, name, attrs = self.prepare_widget_render(widget, attrs, only_initial)
        return widget.render(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Check if current widget has a renderer and iterate renderer.
        """
        widget, name, attrs = self.prepare_widget_render()
        if not hasattr(widget, 'get_renderer'):
            raise Exception, "Can not iterate over widget '%s'" % widget.__class__.__name__
        renderer = widget.get_renderer(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
        for entry in renderer:
            yield entry

    def __getitem__(self,idx):
        """
        Tries to use current widget's renderer, and then check attribute.
        """
        widget, name, attrs = self.prepare_widget_render()
        try:
            renderer = widget.get_renderer(name, self.value(), attrs=attrs)
            return renderer[idx]
        except Exception:
            return getattr(self,idx)

    forms.forms.BoundField.prepare_widget_render = prepare_widget_render
    forms.forms.BoundField.as_widget = as_widget
    forms.forms.BoundField.__iter__ = __iter__
    forms.forms.BoundField.__getitem__ = __getitem__
```

This allowed me to be able to access the radio inputs directly, by using `{{ form.field.0.tag }}`, or through iteration - `{% for radio in form.field %} {{ radio.tag }} {% endfor %}`.  Much easier to take care of!

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can access choices tuple in template:

```
<ul>
    {# Assuming {{ field }} here is {{ form.rad }} #}
    {% for choice in field.field.choices %}
    <li>
        <label for="id_{{ field.html_name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
            <input type="radio"
                id="id_{{ field.html_name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}"
                value="{{ choice.0 }}"
                name="{{ field.html_name }}" />
            {{ choice.1 }}
            {% if choice.0 == 'one' %}
                {# Necessary field here #}
                {{ form.bar }}
            {% else %}
                No Textbox
            {% endif %}
        </label>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a way to  automatically find out the id and name off of the BoundField?  I'll admit, I'm just a tad skittish about putting hard-coded stuff in there, in case I change names, etc.

Comment: I understand. I think, yes, it is: use `{{ field.html_name }}`. And `id` attribute used for input elements is automatically generated as `id_<field_name>`. (See also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

Comment: Okay, I finally got time to apply this... and there's one issue before I'll accept - `form.rad` does not have `choices` - `form.rad.field` does.

Comment: Yeah, I always forget that actual field (`ChoiceField` in this case) is an attribute on `BoundField` instance (you iterate over these in template). Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Choices should be in the Model:

```
class RatherComplicatedModel(models.Model):
    BAR_CHOICES = (
        (0, "No Textbox"),
        (1, "One Textbox: "),
    )
    #some other stuff...
    bar = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=BAR_CHOICES)
```

Then just:

```
class RatherComplicatedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #various and sundry code...
    bar = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), 
                 choices=RatherComplicatedModel.BAR_CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = RatherComplicatedModel
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I guess I wasn't specific enough.  I want the user to be able to enter any arbitrary number into the `bar` box - but the entry is only going to be validated if they have selected the second radio button.  If they select the first radio button (which doesn't display the `bar` box), bar will not be validated.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this by subclassing RadioFieldRenderer and attaching it to a custom widget:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect, RadioFieldRenderer
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from myapp.models import RatherComplicatedModel


class MyRadioFieldRenderer(RadioFieldRenderer):
    def render(self):
        return render_to_string(
            'my_radio_widget.html',
                    {'field': self})


class MyRadioSelect(RadioSelect):
    renderer = MyRadioFieldRenderer


class RatherComplicatedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    RADIO_CHOICES = (
        ('none', "No Textbox"),
        ('one', "One Textbox: "),
    )
    rad = forms.ChoiceField(widget=MyRadioSelect(),choices=RADIO_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = RatherComplicatedModel
```

Then the template:

```
#my_radio_widget.html
<ul>
    {% for choice in field %}
        <li>
            <label for="id_{{ field.name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">
                <input type="radio"
                       name="{{ field.name }}"
                       value="{{ choice.choice_value }}"
                       id="id_{{ field.name }}_{{ forloop.counter0 }}"
                       {% if field.value == choice.choice_value %}
                           checked='checked'
                       {% endif %}/>
                {{ choice.choice_label }}
            </label>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: RadioFieldRenderer is deprecated now